# VBA subtotal column and print in same column

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to run a `=subtotal()` function on an entire column and paste the value in the same column, but you can't run the function in the same column as im trying to total.

```
ActiveCell.Value = "Total No. of chargeable hours"
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Select
ActiveCell.Value = "=SUBTOTAL(9,G:G)"
```

As this returns an error, I have tried using a helper cell to cut and paste but get a debug error on the `PasteSpecial = xlPasteValues` line.

```
ActiveCell.Value = "Total No. of chargeable hours"
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
ActiveCell.Value = "=SUBTOTAL(9,G:G)"
ActiveCell.Cut
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
ActiveCell.PasteSpecial = xlPasteValues
```

The number of rows changes each time the sheet in question is created, so can't use a specific cell range.

Has anyone got a working way to achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: do you mean change `=SUBTOTAL(9,G:G)` to `=SUBTOTAL(G1:G)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Sub WriteSubtotal()

    With ActiveCell
        .Value = "Total No. of chargeable hours."
        .Offset(0, 1).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(9, .Parent.Range("G1").EntireColumn)
    End With

End Sub
```

Generally, you don't need to select or activate cells. Just refer to the cell and manipulate the properties or call the methods. The above sub puts a label in the active cell then changes the Value property of the cell to the right.

Note that the second argument to SUBTOTAL uses the .Parent property. Inside a With block for the ActiveCell, the .Parent property will refer to the sheet.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a formula that returns an array, so you can declare your function as

```
Function SubTotal(InputRange as Range) as Variant
    Dim Output() as Variant
    ' ReDim Output(.... to the correct rows, column size)

    ' Run your subtotal code here
    ' Output (Row, 1) = YourAnswer(Row)

    SubTotal = Output
End Function
```

VBA will not allow a function to modify the spreadsheet with copy paste type operations.

Comment: what do you mean by 'VBA will not allow a function to modify the spreasheet with cop paste type operations'? Not sure i fully understand that bit.

Comment: VBA functions can return values directly, but if you include code in your function to change the formatting of some cell, etc. that'll not be allowed. You will need to enclose your code in a `Sub` instead of a function to modify the spreadsheet. If you need just a UDF, that will only be able to take in arguments and return values back to the cell which it was called from.